# Itens da API não aparecem na Tabela

Tags: react

Preciso preencher uma tabela com todos os itens da minha API, porém quando o processo é finalizado a tabela retorna vazia.
Fiz um fetch para acessar a API e tentei colocar todos os itens dentro de um array dentro do meu state chamado "dados" e dei um setState para preencher esse array com os valores da API.
Em seguida fiz um map em dados para criar uma lista dentro dessa tabela com cada um dos itens preenchidos.
Porém os campos retornam vazios e sem erros...

Achei a API que estou usando meio confusa mas sou obrigado a usa-la... Acredito que o problema seja na nomeação dada no array do meu State que é dados e na API o Array não tem nome. Não sei como proceder.

Por favor esse é um exercício que estou fazendo para aprender React, mas estou empacado, podem me ajudar?

A API que estou usando está rodando no json-server Mockado, mas a estrutura é exatamente igual a do seguinte link: https://gitlab.com/desafio-conta-simples/developer/-/blob/master/mocks/transacoes.json

Segue o código:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {  Container, Row, Col, Table} from 'react-bootstrap'

class Extrato extends Component {        
    constructor(props){
        super(props);    
        this.state = {               
            dados: []                
        }            
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/transacoes")
        .then(resultado => resultado.json().then(dados => this.setState(dados)))
        
    }
   
       
    render() {
        return (
        <Container>
            <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Empresa ID</th>
                    <th>Data Transação</th>
                    <th>Valor</th>
                    <th>Final do Cartão</th>
                    <th>Tipo de Transação</th>
                    <th>Descrição da Transação</th>
                    <th>Estabelecimento</th>
                    <th>Crédito</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
            
                {
                         this.state.dados.map((item, indice) => {
                          return (
                            <tr key={indice}>
                            <td>{item.empresaId}</td>
                            <td>{item.dataTransacao}</td>
                            <td>{item.valor}</td>
                            <td>{item.finalCartao}</td>
                            <td>{item.tipoTransacao}</td>
                            <td>{item.descricaoTransacao}</td>
                            <td>{item.estabelecimento}</td>
                            <td>{item.credito}</td>
                            </tr>
                           )
                         })
                 }
        
                    
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </Container>
        )
    }
    
}

export default Extrato;
```

Comment: tem um erro no seu jsx ... verifique deve estar dando erro.

Comment: Verifiquei, não há erros na aplicação. Quando dou o npm start ela roda normalmente só que sem preencher a tabela e no console também não há erros. O que eu vi que tinha a mais eram duas importações do bootstrap, mas já apaguei e a tabela continua vazia.

Comment: Pode ser mais adequado para uma pergunta do que para um comentário, mas no caso essa Array da API não tem nome, nos vídeos que eu vi todas as Arrays da API tem nome, nesse caso o Array da API não tem nome, como eu indico que aquela Array do State deve receber o valor da Array da API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com a quantidade de duvidas resolvi exemplificar como deveria ser o seu código, foi criado um `fake` do `JSON` e no momento da criação do componente carregado essa informação, depois no método `render()` foi mostrado os dados contidos no `JSON`, exemplo mínimo:

```js
const json = [
    {
        "empresaId": 1,
        "dataTransacao": "2020-09-01T09:50:00",
        "valor": 5000.0,
        "finalCartao": null,
        "tipoTransacao": "TED_IN",
        "descricaoTransacao": "Transferencia recebida",
        "estabelecimento": null,
        "credito": true,
    },
    {
        "empresaId": 2,
        "dataTransacao": "2020-09-01T10:50:00",
        "valor": 5000.0,
        "finalCartao": null,
        "tipoTransacao": "SLIP_IN",
        "descricaoTransacao": "Deposito por Boleto",
        "estabelecimento": null,
        "credito": true,
    }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      transacoes: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({transacoes: json});    
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.transacoes.map(c => 
          <div>
            <div>{c.empresaId}</div>
            <div>{c.dataTransacao}</div>
            <hr />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

Comment: Se tiver algo errado na resposta podem dizer eu estou aqui para arrumar?

Comment: Desculpe te alugar Novic, entendi a proposta fiz a seguinte alteração  no meu código porém eu não devo estar sabendo como fazer...                             
Porque não funcionou.
        componentDidMount(){
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/transacoes")
        .then(resultado => resultado.json().then(dados => this.setState(transacoes: dados)))
        
    }

Comment: Sim não está mesmo, precisa @Toquinhoro para e estudar `Javascript` para depois cair em `ReactJs` é o caminho natural, se vai ver.

Comment: aqui é assim`this.setState({transacoes: dados})` entre chaves

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado. Vou rever JavaScript após terminar esse exercício.